# Web application's payroll data integration with QuickBooks

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbwc

I want to Integrate my C#.NET web application with QuickBook online edition.

I am new to this and using asp.net 3.5 framework for my application. I want to integrate my application's employee payroll data to QBOE for creating PayChecks. So what API should  I use? I have read and downloaded QBWC, but not getting much idea or steps.

Please help me to satisfy application requirements.

Thanks in advance,
Vimal

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the Web Connector with QuickBooks Online Edition. The Web Connector is for use only with desktop versions of QuickBooks.

QuickBooks Online Edition provides an HTTP API that you can use to communicate with it. Basically, you send HTTP POST requests with XML data to the QuickBooks Online server, and it responds with XML responses.

There is some documentation showing the setup process in the QuickBooks SDK and on my wiki:
[QuickBooks Online setup process](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition)

And some example XML requests/responses as well:
[Example qbXML request/response](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition#example_qbxml_for_online_edition)

Further documentation on qbXML requests you can send can be found here:
[QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html)

It should be noted that you *cannot* create paychecks. Intuit does not give you the ability to create paychecks programatically. The closest you can get is creating Time Tracking sheets with the TimeTrackingAdd request, which can then be converted to paychecks/payroll entries within the QuickBooks Online GUI.

Comment: `*It should be noted that you cannot create paychecks. Intuit doe..* ` - not even for Quickbooks desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the QuickBooks SDK will give you the broadest range of access to online edition data.  However, you won't be able to create paychecks.  The closest you can get to the payroll data is to create time sheet entries, which the user can convert into paychecks by using the QuickBooks payroll process.  The paychecks themselves and everything you see on the payroll screen is locked down by Intuit.

It should be noted that the QuickBooks SDK is very flexible and gives you access to almost all areas of the program, but not payroll, sorry.  You can create expense checks with the SDK, but I doubt that will be adequate for a payroll solution.